# Shell script attrib +r Parameter format not correct -

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a git hook to checkout the master branch of a bare repository and put it in a folder. Then I need that to be read-only so people don't accidentally change it and break it.

I am testing this as a .sh file, because it is much easier to trigger.

**This is all working nicely:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# after receiving, populates a folder called "LatestMaster" in the *.git directory.
# Folder contains the working copy of the master branch.
# All working tree items are made to be read-only so they cannot be modified accidentally
# 4 March 2016 Matt Tarabulski

# relative path of shell script
MY_PATH="`dirname \"$0\"`"              

# absolutized and normalized path
MY_PATH="`( cd \"$MY_PATH\" && pwd )`"  

# move one above the hooks folder
MY_PATH="$MY_PATH""/../LatestMaster"    

# make the directory one above the hooks directory
mkdir -p "$MY_PATH"                     

if [ -z "$MY_PATH" ] ; then
  # error; for some reason, the path is not accessible
  # to the script (e.g. permissions re-evaled after suid)
  echo "post-receive hook could not write to LatestMaster folder"
  exit 1  # fail
fi
# set the work tree env var to $MY_PATH and export to be usable later in this script
export GIT_WORK_TREE="$MY_PATH"         

# Make the head writeable for checkout
attrib -r "$MY_PATH/../HEAD"            
git checkout master -f -q
```

**Here's where it breaks**

```
# Make the working copy read only so people don't lose work
attrib +r "$MY_PATH" /s /d
```

Output: Parameter format not correct -

I feel like I've tried every combination of quotes, search paths etc. and no matter what I get either parameter format not correct or

for example with this code:

```
attrib +r "$MY_PATH/*.*"" /s"
```

I get path not found, even though it definitely exists. Appreciate any help on this one.

I am using windows 7, and the path is a mapped network drive if that makes any difference

when I do
    attrib +r /s

in cmd in the folder it works perfectly, so I think it may have to do with my use of a variable

if i do in my script:
    cd "$MY_PATH"
    attrib +r /s
I get S: not found

OK i figured it out:

```
cd "$MY_PATH"
attrib +r '//s'
```

works perfectly. Anyone know why?

Comment: Please learn to use `$(…)` instead of back-ticks.  You don't need a second sub-shell for the `cd` and `pwd` combination; the command expansion already runs the operations in a sub-shell.  You have: `MY_PATH="$MY_PATH/../LatestMaster"`, but you could simplify that to `MY_PATH="$MY_PATH""/../LatestMaster"`.  Since `MY_PATH` contains `/../LatestMaster`, it will never be a zero length string, so the `-z` test will never succeed — you may as well remove it.